# What version of the .NET Core SDK is installed

Tags: .net

How can I tell what versions of the .NET Core SDK are installed. How can I tell and which one is being used?

Answer (score 16):

```
 dotnet --version
```

Displays the version being used.

```
dotnet --list-sdks
```

Lists the versions installed. Requires  .NET Core SDK 2.1 and later.

See also See [Windows or Visual Studio can't find the latest installed .NET SDK due to bitness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67049414/windows-or-visual-studio-cant-find-the-latest-installed-net-sdk-due-to-bitness)

**Windows key** > **apps & features** and search on **.net core**. From **apps & features** you can uninstall SDKs you're not using.

Comment: You might make it clear that the latter only works for .NET Core SDK 2.1.xxx and above. I don't think old SDKs support it.

Comment: No, older SDKs don't support the second option. Only 2.1+.

Comment: Note that in Add/Remove Programs in Control Panel, the 1.x SDKs are listed as ".NET Core SDK 1.x", while the 2.x are listed as "**Microsoft** .NET Core SDK 2.x".